# Grouping by DATEPART(hh,TimeStamp) to show nightshift, how do I see data for hours past midnight?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I'm importing my data to excel and so I need to see the date as a varchar to use for a graph in excel but I also need the data for the individual hours in the day as well. My manager wants to see data for the past hour whenever he checks my chart. This is my code so far. Dayshift has been fine but I can't get the hours to go past 24 for nightshift so I can't group them in my graph in excel.

```
convert(VARCHAR, TimeStamp, 101) as date
    ,StationID as lane 
    ,DATEPART(hh,TimeStamp)
        ,.185 as posSD1 
    ,-.185 as negSD1
    ,.370 as posSD2
    ,-.370 as negSD2
    ,.556 as posSD3
    ,-.556 as negSD3


    , COUNT (TrickleActual) as Count
    , convert(decimal (18,3) ,AVG (TrickleActual - TrickleTarget)) as Average



FROM CherryBoxInfo

WHERE TimeStamp >= '2015-05-01'         -- '2015-05-01 18:30:00'
    and  TimeStamp between convert(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR, TimeStamp, 101) + ' ' + '19:00:00') and convert(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR, DATEADD(day, 1, TimeStamp), 101) + ' ' + '04:30:00')
    and (TrickleActual-TrickleTarget) BETWEEN -1 and 1



GROUP BY
    convert(VARCHAR, TimeStamp, 101)
    ,StationID
    ,DATEPART(hh,TimeStamp) 



ORDER BY convert(VARCHAR, TimeStamp, 101)
,StationID
,DATEPART(hh,TimeStamp)
```

Comment: Always tag proper dbms..also desired output you are expecting and sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of grouping on datepart, group on date truncated to hour.

Here is how to truncate a date:

```
select dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, @dt), 0)
```